# Dynamically switching between ADO.NET entity models

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

This is .net 4 in vs 2010. I have multiple databases with the same structure. We will eventually merge them into one but thats way down the line. Im writing an application and to keep from having to write the same code 10 times, I want to dynamically switch between models. I'm close but not quite there. Heres what i have:

```
using esOrderHeader = Shipping.Models.esShip.OrderHeader;

using fnOrderHeader = Shipping.Models.fnShip.OrderHeader; //OrderHeader is a table in the database

    ObjectContext context = null;

    IEnumerable< EntityObject> orderHeader = null; //i've tried ObjectSet as well

    switch (client)
    {

         case "es":
                  context = new esshipEntities();
                  orderHeader = context.CreateObjectSet<esOrderHeader>();
                  break;

         case "fn":
                  context = new fnshipEntities();
                  orderHeader = context.CreateObjectSet<fnOrderHeader>();
                  break;

    }

var query = from row in orderHeader where row.IsFulfilled == false select row;
```

The following wont compile because the compiler says "Cannot resolve symbol IsFulfilled" which is a field in my table. How can I switch between entities and be able to run linq queries against them?

Comment: It cannot resolve row.IsFulfilled because orderHeader is of type IEnumerable<EntityObject>. I'm not sure if this will work, but could you try to make a superclass for your Shipping.Models.esShip.OrderHeader (and fnShip also), and put IsFulfilled property there, and then use that superclass instead of EntityObject? I'm gonna try that also, let you know if it works for me...

Comment: Btw, instead of 'row.IsFulfilled == false' you could just put in '!row.IsFulfilled' :)

Comment: Well, mine compiled successfully (Can't test without making a database though). Did you have any luck?

Comment: Please give that a try and if it works, post your example. I'm not sure how to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: Do both fnShip.OrderHeader and esShip.OrderHeader have the same properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What will help you make your code **compile** (although I'm not sure if it is a good solution :) ), is making a superclass for OrderHeaders for different ships.

```
namespace Shipping.Models
{
    class CommonOrderHeader
    {
        public bool IsFulfilled { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Shipping.Models.fnShip
{
    class OrderHeader : CommonOrderHeader
    {

    }
}

namespace Shipping.Models.esShip
{
    class OrderHeader : CommonOrderHeader
    {

    }
}
```

This way, instead of `IEnumerable<EntityObject> orderHeader = null;` you use `IEnumerable<CommonOrderHeader> orderHeader = null;`

Since `EntityObject` does not contain the property `IsFulfilled`, your code doesn't compile. `CommonOrderHeader` contains this field and so, your code compiles.

Hope you get this to work :)

Comment: Thanks for posting and I hope i get this to work too. I dont see how i can get this to work this way, because the entity model classes were autogenerated by visual studio and this wouldnt be a problem if the designer put the tables for the models in the same class as the model and not in separate classes. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Yes, i know what youre saying, that might pose a problem, however, I have another solution in mind: If you're unable to use a superclass due to them being generated, you could use a class that has properties of interest (i.e the ones youre trying to select), and then put your query inside the switch and make it return objects of that type. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: If im understanding what you're saying, wouldn't that be what im trying to avoid meaning repeated code?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. :) It's just that I don't see another way you could even use this data you select, unless it's of one type (i.e IEnumerable<SomeNewClass>, or a supertype). Incidentally - how did you plan to extract data from EntityObject?

Comment: The classes that all tables inherit from is EntityObject, so I assumed i could.

Comment: If you find a way to do that (something like entityObjectInstance.getProperty("propertyName"), then you can probably use that in your linq query.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK to me... Can you check if the "IsFulfilled" property of the entity is being mapped properly to the database table? The "Orderheader" is actually supposed to be an Ienumerable ..this is what you write your linq query against..right? The only thing I could think of is if the object is being mapped right? Also, are esshipentities and fnshipentities in two seperate edmx files??

Comment: yes esshipentities and fnshipentities are two seperate edmx files.  IsFulfilled is mapped properly because I have ran queries against the OrderHeader table when I instantiated my object like this:

Comment: var orderHeader = context.CreateObjectSet<esOrderHeader>();